# Is there a way to replace one image with another using a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have a display that shows something of a RAG status when certain checkboxes are clicked, example:

if no boxes are checked, show image 1 (grey)

if the first box is checked, show image 2 (red)

if both boxes are checked, show image 3 (green)

This is meant to show that a system is not impacted (grey), whether it is offline (red) or was offline but has now recovered (green).

I have an html checkbox and an html image with ID tags, as well as all 3 images uploaded to the site I'll be adding this into, with the following code script embedded in the html.  Once this is working, can someone advise how to make the grey icon show again once the boxes are unchecked, that would be great - will the If statements work on uncheck, as it's an on-click event?

Javascript:

```
  function customerImpact();
    var customerImpactIcon = documet.getElementById("customerImpactIcon");
    var customerImpact = document.getElementById("customerImpact");
    var customerImpactCleared = document.getElementById("customerImpactCleared");

     if (customerImpact == true){
      if (customerImpactCleared == true){
       customerImpactIcon.src="image3.jpg"
       }
      else {
       customerImpactIcon.src="image2.jpg"
       }
      }
     else { 
      customerImpactIcon.src="image1.jpg"
      }
     }
```

HTML:

```
<img src="image1.jpg" id="customerImpactIcon" alt="customerImpact" width="70" height="118" />
<input type="checkbox" id="customerImpact" onclick="customerImpact()">
<input type="checkbox" id="customerImpactCleared">
```

Comment: First, `Java` is not same as `Javascript`. Second, are the images in same folder? If not, you will have to give proper path. Third and more important, `function customerImpact();` is wrong. It should be an opening brace

Comment: Third, your function should be `function customerImpact(){...}` and not `function customerImpact();`

Comment: There is another typos: `customerImpactIcon = documet.`. but your code is almost correct. [Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/4dhrvcq8/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to change your HTML a little, you don't need Javascript at all. Using CSS would be sufficient.

```css
#status {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/100/33333");
}

#customerImpact:checked+#customerImpactCleared:not(:checked)+#status {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/100/FF0000");
}

#customerImpact:checked+#customerImpactCleared:checked+#status {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/100/008000");
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="customerImpact">
<input type="checkbox" id="customerImpactCleared">
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: This looks good - would the CSS be embedded in the html, or would it come under a separate .css file?

Comment: @GetWhimsical I personally would use a separate .css file

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are querying for the checkbox `HTMLElement`s and checking for their truthiness (`customerImpact == true`). They will always be truthy regardless of whether they are checked or not. You want to *check* if the `checked` property on the checkboxes is true.

I made a small example (without images, but it should be easy for you adapt it). I also opted to use the `change` event instead of the `click` event.

```js
const status = document.querySelector('[data-status]');

function update() {
  const customerImpact = document.querySelector('[data-customer-impact]').checked;
  const customerImpactCleared = document.querySelector('[data-customer-impact-cleared]').checked;
  
  if (customerImpact && customerImpactCleared) {
    status.textContent = 'Recovered';
  } else if (customerImpact) {
    status.textContent = 'Offline';
  } else {
    status.textContent = 'No impact';
  }
}

update();
```

```html
<p data-status></p>

<input id="customer-impact" type="checkbox" data-customer-impact onchange="update()">
<label for="customer-impact">Customer Impact</label><br>

<input id="customer-impact-cleared" type="checkbox" data-customer-impact-cleared onchange="update()">
<label for="customer-impact-cleared">Customer Impact Cleared</label>
```

Comment: I've tried replicating the code across, but for some reason the data-status paragraph doesn't show anything - is the javascript element required to be in a separate .js file, or can it be embedded in the html?